# How to create a JSON formatted request from an HTML form?

Tags: json, request

This is a beginner question.  I've done as much homework as I can, so I'm asking for help since I'm stuck.

I'm trying to create an application to learn REST, and I'd like to format my request data as JSON.

I'm starting with the HTML form to first confirm the 'sent' or request data is correct, but don't see it being sent as part of an HTTP request in the browser dev tools (Firefox).  I have a server running, and I can open the page through my localhost, but there is no client/backend code yet, such as a Java Servlet - all I have right now is my HTML form with a 'submit' button, open in localhost in my browser.

My intention is to confirm JSON formatted data is being created and sent.  If I need more infrastructure, please let me know - I'm not sure if the test I'm running to generate a request is possible with just an HTML form, but no client Java code yet.

I've applied "enctype='application/json'" to the form, which I believe should format the form data as JSON.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype='application/json' name='testForm' method="post">
  <input name='name' value='JSONForm'>
  <select name='hind'>
    <option selected>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
  </select>
  <input type='checkbox' name='shiny' checked>
  <input type='button' value='SubmitForm'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the request and response headers.

There was also a 'Response' pane, but not a 'Request' pane, so I'm not sure how to view the data sent - or maybe I haven't created a request at all.

So, how do I confirm/view that I've created and sent JSON data?  How do I 'send' the data - is clicking the 'submit' button enough to 'send' the data in a request?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried uploading screen shots of my dev tools page, but they're not appearing.  The upload replaced my images with links, which I bracketed with "<>" per the instructions, but I still don't see them.  Suggestions?

Comment: should not need to include extra symbols to post images, should be able to upload images just by clicking the `Image` button and "Drag or Drop" your image into the question form, or link to an image already on Imgur

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a button of type button doesn't submit the form, only
`<button type="submit">` or `<input type="button">`.
Also, I don't think that it's possible to change the way a form is formatted via HTML, only JavaScript. In order to do that you need to add a script to catch the values from your inputs, and then to build you JSON object and send it via an AJAX post.
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-ajax-send-web-form/